# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS cannot login 'invalid password' (not redirect loop)

Tags: 14.04, login, password

I updated it, and while logged on I change my password, restarted the computer, and could not log back in. How to change password from guest account? I can't download anything, I tried ctrl+alt+F1 but even there it's 'wrong password'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it from guest account. And next time be more careful while typing your password.

Get an Ubuntu Live media (the same you used to install it) and boot your computer from it. In a terminal, run:

`sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt`

Replacing XY with the appropriate letter/number to your Ubuntu partition.

`sudo chroot /mnt`

`sudo passwd username`

Replace `username` with (captain Obvious) your username. A new password will be asked and you'll have to type it again to confirm. nothing will be showed on the screen while you type. **Double check every single character before typing it**. Reboot and you should be able to login with your new password.

Comment: how do you get to terminal just ctrl alt t while its loading

Comment: what the heck is a partition how do i find out what that is

Comment: You can't be serious... The partition we want is the first (and I suppose only) part of your external disk. Run `lsblk` and, by comparing the partition sizes, discover what is yours. Probably something like /dev/sdb1.

Comment: Where do I run terminal? The screen that pops up first when the live thing is plugged in it says 'try ubuntu without downloading' and 'download ubuntu'  and stuff like that.

Comment: I edited my qquestion. Man, seriously. You should at least know what a terminal is. It is a program. Just look for it in the dash.

Comment: I trying doing it from recovery mode. I did sudo mount/dev/sdXY /mnt but then it said /dev/sdXY already mounted or /mnt busy. Then proceeded to the other steps but then when I typed in the new password it said passwd: Authentication token manipulation error

Comment: Does “the disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present” have anything to do with it?

Comment: What did you do to get this?

Comment: no idea just tell me how to fix this. so when I first have the live media plugged in, which one do I select? "Run Ubuntu without Installing" "Install Ubuntu" "Start from hard disk" which one? (I have it installed) and if I don't have the live media, do I select "advanced options">>"Recovery mode"?

Comment: should I just revert to my old windows xp and reinstall ubuntu? But then I'd have to download all the things for steam again and it takes too long...

Comment: I got the comment while it was doing normal loading.